# How does computer identify routers differently?

Tags: electromagnetism, radio-frequency

Every router has its own name. What is physics that use in making router ideal one from another? Why we can't use same password to access all the routers? I know it sounds crazy but they all use 5GHz frequency for data transferring. I request the physics of it?

Comment: This is less of a physics question and more of a software question.  You might get better luck on Electronics.SE.

Comment: thank you for your advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Routers don't all use exactly 5GHz Roughly speaking they use 20-40 MHz slices of the allowed range between 5.725 GHz - 5.875 GHz. When all the bands are filled, then you can't add another router without disrupting the others.

Comment: thank you for your corporation.